# I Cant Delete Data from fetch in react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, fetch

I have a **MERN app**, used Fetch API. I want to delete specific data upon clicking.

Whenever i am clicking on **delete its showing 'cannot delete.'**

and **Status is 404: Not Found**

Here is my front end code please help me with this

**What I have tried:**

```
import {useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {

  const userArr = [
    {}
  ]

 const [form, setForm] = useState(userArr);
 const [users,setUsers] = useState([]);
 
 const [sid,setId] = useState("");
 const [fname, setFName] = useState("");
 const [pass,setPass] = useState("");




 const handleName = (e) =>{
    setFName(e.target.value);
  
   
 }

 const handlePass = (e) =>{
  setPass(e.target.value);
  console.log("pass is -->"+pass)
 }

 const handleForm = (e) =>{
  setId(Math.random()+1);
  setForm({
    ...form,
    userid: sid,
    username:fname,
    password:pass
  })
 }

 const removeElm = (userid) =>{

  fetch(`http://localhost:9090/demo/users/${userid}`, {
    method: "DELETE",
    headers: {
     'content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  })
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then((err) => console.log(err))
    .then(() => {
      setUsers(values => {
        return values.filter(item => item.userid !== userid)
      })
      
 })

}

 const handleSubmit = async (e) =>{
  e.preventDefault();
  const response = await fetch("http://localhost:9090/demo",{
    method:'POST',
    body:JSON.stringify(form),
    headers:{
      'Content-Type':'application/json'
    }
  })

  const data = await response.json();
  console.log(form);
  console.log(response);
  console.log(data);
 }

 const getUsers = async () =>{
  const response = await fetch("http://localhost:9090/demo",{
    method:'GET',
  })

  const data = await response.json();
  setUsers(data);
 }
    
 useEffect(()=>{
  getUsers();
 },[])

  return (
    <div className="App">
     <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
       <input type="text" name='username' onChange={handleName} />
       <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
       <input type="text" name='password' onChange={handlePass} />
       <button onClick={handleForm}>Submit</button>
      </form>
     </div>
     <ul>
     {users.map(obj=><li key={obj.userid}> <span>Username:{obj.username}</span>, <span>Password:{obj.password}</span>  <button onClick={() => removeElm(obj._id)}>Remove</button> </li>
   )}
     </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Backend**

```js
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


// mongo db
main().catch(err => console.log(err));

async function main() {
  await mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/demo');
  console.log('db connected');
}

// schema
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      userid: Number,
    username: String,
    password: String
  });

// model- class from schema
const UserModel= mongoose.model("User",userSchema);
console.log(UserModel) // to check if the Model has been created successfully or not


const server = express();
// middleware
server.use(cors());
server.use(bodyParser.json());

// API
//CRUD - Create
server.post('/demo',async (req,res)=>{
    let user = new UserModel();
    user.userid  = req.body.userid;
    user.username = req.body.username;
    user.password = req.body.password;
    // save function
    const savedDoc = await user.save();
    console.log(savedDoc);
    res.json(savedDoc);
})

//CRUD - Read
server.get('/demo',async (req,res)=>{
  const docs =  await UserModel.find({});
  console.log("All Docs=>"+docs);
  res.json(docs);
})

server.listen(9090,()=>{
    console.log(`Server is running on port 9090`);
})
```

I want to delete specific data upon clicking.

Please help me with this.

Comment: There is no delete endpoint in your express backend. You do realize that you only have get and post endpoints in your backend right? and that you need a separate endpoint to delete?

Comment: yaa, if thats the case, how to to add that.

Comment: How did you create the removeElm if you did not have any endpoint for delete in the first place? Did you copy this from somewhere?

Comment: I have taken idea from a youtube video, i didn't copied, removeElm will trigger upon clicking delete, i didn't  have any idea about any end point of delete, if you know please share with me.

Comment: I have already told you what you need to do, yo need to create an endpoint for delete. Look it up do some research, its very similar to you get and post endpoints.

Comment: Yaa searched for it, and got an answer below too. You can check this. I have to add the endpoing in the server and used object i given by default . You can check below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TRY THIS:-**

**Front end for removing element**

```js
  const removeElm =  (id) =>{
  
    fetch(`http://localhost:8080/2ndapp/users/${id}`, {
      method: "DELETE",
      headers: {
       'content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    })
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then((response) => console.log(response.status, response.statusText))
      .then(() => {
        setUsers(values => {
          return values.filter(item => item.id !== id)
        })
  })
  
   }
```

**Server side you add this**

```js
 server.delete("/demo/users/:id", async (req, res) => {
    try{
      const idToDelete = req.params.id;
      console.log("-->Its Running");
      const deletedDoc =await UserModel.findByIdAndDelete({"_id": new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(idToDelete)});
      console.log("Its Running2"); 
      return res.status(204).send('Deleted');
        }catch(err){
        new Error(err);
      };
  });
```

You should use Object ID which mongo has provided.

Comment: Thanks bro this is working am using object id now.

Comment: Its okay bro cheers